# Why is this if with initializer not true?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, c++20

```cpp
int* get(){return nullptr;}

int main()
{
   if(auto p = get(); (*p) != 1231231233)
   {
        std::cout << "NO";   // not printed
   }
   else
   {
        std::cout << "we should be here" << std::endl;;   
   }
}
```

Why is here not `NO` printed, because according to the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), the *init-statement* is not checked to true and the access to `*p` should be UB and we should result in `true` ?. I am puzzled:
[LIVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dc1c74116d0ed22)

Comment: Why would you think that UB would result in true? "True" would be *defined behavior*, and UB is by definition undefined behavior.

Comment: I again forgot about the fact that UB whatever can happen...

Comment: @Gabriel If the answer solves your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please include [c++] in your tags as well as the specific version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dereferencing a nullptr inside the `if`-clause, which is undefined behavior. The compiler is basically allowed to do whatever it wants with that piece of code. You can't make any assumptions about what will happen when `(*p)` is executed.

Comment: I just find out. Thx.